# I have a US based company that does business in Europe, and contracts freelancers in other countries. What forms do I need to file?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, contractor

I run a software consulting company. I get projects mostly in the US, but recently I closed a deal with a company from Germany. Most of the people I want to hire to finish this project are based in Latin America.

So my questions are:

1. What forms do I need to file to receive money from Europe
2. What forms do I need to file to pay people in Latin America (or any country outside the US)
3. Can I deduct payments I made to contractors from other countries as company expense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more about running a firm than individual finances.

Comment: True, this is not really a personal finance question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1. What forms do I need to file to receive money from Europe*

None. Your client can pay you via wire transfer. They need to know your name, address, account number, and the name of your bank, its SWIFT number and its associated address. The addresses and names are required to make sure there are no typos in the numbers.

*2. What forms do I need to file to pay people in Latin America (or any country outside the US)*

None. 1099s only need to be filled out when the contractor has a US tax ID. Make sure they are contractors. If they work for you for more than 2 years, that can create a problem unless they incorporate because they might look like "employees" to the IRS in which case you need to be reporting their identitites to the IRS via a W-8BEN form. Generally speaking any foreign contractor you have for more than 2 years should incorporate in their own country and you bill that corporation to prevent employee status from occurring.

*3. Can I deduct payments I made to contractors from other countries as company expense*

Of course.

Comment: Wait - regarding point 2.  Company X in the USA, pays $5000 to some programmer P. P is either a human or company entity. P is overseas, in say Germany, Brazil or China.  In fact, isn't it the case that company X ***must*** simply collect from P, the W8BEN-E form.  Right?

Comment: @JoeBlow No, you only have to identify foreign employees to the IRS, not contractors.